# jVisualVM - JIT activity metrics

Tags: java, monitoring, jvisualvm

I've just tested some J2EE containers with jVisualVM, but I have troubles with correctly interpreting scores. I saw that values of JIT activity often are over 100% (sometimes 800%). What does it mean? I've read that JIT activity are counted based on number of processors, but if so I have only 2 processors and max. percentage activity should be 200%.

Any explain?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did not *calibrate* jVisualVM right?

Did you have any load while performing calibration? Then your numbers will likely be off.

Comment: I think I calibrated jVisualVm correctly. During calibration process there wasn't running any Java application.

Comment: I've just calibrated jVisualVM again and trouble is still the same. If I tests WebSphere container with its own JVM everything is OK.